# Sorting ArrayList<String[]>

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an array with the following syntax:

```
ArrayList<String[]> outerArr = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String[] str = {art1, art2, String.valueOf(sim)};
outerArr.add(str);
```

After certain loops and changes, I get something like:

```
name1 name2 0.11
name1 name3 0.14
name2 name4 0.12
```

I need to sort them by the third column. How is it possible to implement?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort

Comment: Why not implement a Comparable interface in your class to pick out a specific value to sort by?

Comment: First off... what are these "certain loops and changes"

Comment: use Collections.sort() with a Comparator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be forewarned that this will compare lexicographically - that is, if you have numbers 1.0, 2.0, 10.0,11.0, and 20.0, the order will be 1.0, 10.0, 11.0, 2.0, and 20.0.

This is a very rudimentary approach in Java 8 using a simple `Comparator`.  Be cautioned that this won't check for null on either side.

```
Comparator<String[]> stringArrayComparator = (left, right) ->
                         left[2].compareTo(right[2]);
```

You could then use this in `Collections.sort`.

```
Collections.sort(outerArr, stringArrayComparator);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Column Comparator](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/16/column-comparator/) which is a general purpose `Comparator` that allows you to specify the column you want to sort on.

The `ColumnComparator` will work on data stored in a Array or a List.

If you don't want to use that class, the blog also shows how to create a simple `Comparator for a given column in the`Array`.